# How to convert content:// to file after image capture android?

Tags: android

I am capturing image using camera in android using the following code snippet.

```
 Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(Constants.ATTACH_IMAGE);
 imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
imageIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());startActivityForResult(imageIntent, Constants.ATTACH_IMAGE);
```

in onActivityResult, I want to convert the "content://" uri back to File, compress it and show a thumb nail.
How can I do it?

Edit :-

What I have tried:-

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.d("activity result","coming" + String.valueOf(requestCode)+ contentFileUri);
//        View popupView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_add_snag, null);
//        LinearLayout attachLayout = (LinearLayout)popupView.findViewById(R.id.attachLayout);
//        ImageView photoImageicon = (ImageView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.imageicon);

        try{
//            if (resultCode == Constants.RESULT_OK){
                if(contentFileUri !=null) {
                    Log.d("fileuri", contentFileUri.toString());
                    String attachmentType = "IMAGE";
//                        mAdapter.attachmentType=attachmentType;
                    photoImageIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // attachLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.string.successfull_image, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("fileuri", contentFileUri.toString());

                    InputStream inputStream =   getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentFileUri);
```

contentFileUri looks like this:- "content://com.fa.ha.provider/external_files/F/7c7.jpeg"

But above results in "FileNotFound Exception, not a directory" at the last line.

Comment: `File file = new File(fileUri.getPath())`?

Comment: This is not a fileUri that is the problem, it is a contentUri.

Comment: see `ContentResolver#openInputStream`

Comment: @pskink I tried not working.

Comment: and i tried, `openInputStream` is working

Comment: Yes. ContentResolver#openInputStream() will do it. Show what you tried. In your post please.

Comment: @greenapps. fileNotFoundException not a directory. 
My argument to the function looks somewhat like this.
"content://com.fa.ha.provider/external_files/F/7c7.jpeg"

Comment: You did not post the requested code. So you cannot be helped.

Comment: @greenapps Please see the edits.

Comment: `InputStream inputStream =   getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentFileUri);` contentFileUri? What is contentFileUri? Should we guess?

Comment: @greenapps It was already mentioned in an above comment, however I have added that in the question now.

Comment: There should be a contentFileUri in your code as you should show us what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, just hang onto the `File` that `getOutputMediaFileUri()` is creating. Hopefully, `getOutputMediaFileUri()` is setting up a `FileProvider` `Uri` for you, based off of a `File`, so if you hold onto the `File`, you do not need to worry about "converting" anything. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.5/Camera/FileProvider).

If `getOutputMediaFileUri()` is poorly written, perhaps you do not have a `File`. In that case, in `onActivityResult()`, you can pass the `Uri` to an image-loading library (Picasso, Glide, etc.) and have it populate an `ImageView` or simply load the `Bitmap` for you.

Comment: Thanks....
But both are in different fragments (the getOutputMediaFileUri() and onActivityResult(), so I have to create a member variable for the file, is there any way I can avoid it?
ie, To recreate the file from the Uri, just for information sake I am asking.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat: "is there any way I can avoid it?" -- no. You would need a field/member variable for the `Uri` anyway. After all, as the documentation shows, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not return anything, such as your `Uri`.

Comment: You made a good point there.

But asking a general question.
Is there any way I can convert Content Uri to File?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat: You were already told how to do that in the comments. Call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, supplying the `Uri`. Open a `FileOutputStream` on some file that you control. Use standard Java I/O to copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`. Then use the resulting file.